# Reconnect To Previous Puppeteer Session In Hosted Environment

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

I'm currently working on a project that uses Puppeteer to control headless chrome. Right now I'm hosting my app using Firebase functions. This is working well if I have to do all my browsing in one session, but if I have to come back at a later time I am having trouble reestablishing a connection and resuming where I left off.

Here is my current script.

```
const express = require('express');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const db = admin.database();
const app = express();

app.get('/openpage', async (req, res) => {

  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox'] });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    const url = 'https://www.reddit.com/';
    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    await page.evaluate(() => {
      document.querySelector('input[name="q"]').value = 'dog';
      document.querySelector('[action="/search"]').submit();
    });

    // Here I want to save the current state of the browser
    const endpoint = browser.wsEndpoint();
    console.log('Endpoint', endpoint);
    db.ref('test/').update({ endpoint });
    await browser.close();

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  res.send('Finished');
});

app.get('/screenshot', async (req, res) => {

  try {
    const endpoint = await db.ref('test/endpoint').once('value').then(snap => snap.val());
    const browser = await puppeteer.connect({ browserWSEndpoint: endpoint }); // This is where it fails
    const pages = await browser.pages();
    const page = pages[0];
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'picture' });
    await browser.close();

  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
  res.send('Finished');
})

exports.test = functions.runWith({ memory: '2GB', timeoutSeconds: 60 }).https.onRequest(app);
```

With this setup, I can make a request to the `/openpage` endpoint and everything works fine and I store the browser endpoint to the firebase realtime database. But when I try to resume the session by calling `/screenshot` I get an error that the connection gets refused on the browser.connect() method. Is there a different way I should be going about this? Is this a firebase limitation or am I missing something about how the connections are reestablished in Puppeteer?

Error message: `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:62222`

On a side note you have to add `"engines": { "node": "8" },` to your package.json to be able to run Puppeteer with Firebase Functions.

Answer (score 4):

This is because you are closing your browser with this line, `await browser.close();`. This will disconnect and close the browser and you won't be able to connect again.

You should use `browser.disconnect()` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I've done a bunch of testing on this and did figure out that I'm supposed to use `disconnect` rather than `close`. But it seems like this doesn't work in the context of Firebase functions because everytime the function completes the app spins down and puppeteer cannot reconnect the browser to resume where it left off. I'm currently experimenting with other providers like Google App Engine and Heroku with a traditional Express app to see if this is possible.